# Fill out web form with data from outlook message VB/VBA

Tags: vb.net, forms, vba, web, outlook

I would like to create a macro for outlook.

I need to extract the selected e-mails subject, from-line, and body and pre populate 3 text fields on a website with that data.

I can already do this by URL (website/form.php?name=xxx&subject=xxx&message=xxxx)

Either

1. the macro extracts the 3 fields from selected message and builds the prepopulated link to send user to.
2. the macro logs into said site and fills in the data on the form.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try to keep the questions short and to the point - maybe a scroll through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) first?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input, I have simplified my question, hoping I can get an upvote!

Comment: "I would like to create a macro for Outlook" - what is stopping you from doing that? What **exactly** are you having a problem with?

Comment: Look at the entries at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861252.aspx to get some idea of how to extract the required info from an Outlook email

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

http://developers.phpjunkyard.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=4241

You'll find my code there.

```
Sub HelpdeskNewTicket()
Dim helpdeskaddress As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String
Dim oldmsg As String
Dim senderaddress As String
Dim addresstype As Integer
Dim ie         As Object
Dim sResult    As String
Dim dtTimer    As Date
Dim lAddTime   As Long


Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()


' Sender E=mail Address
senderaddress = objItem.SenderEmailAddress

'Searches for @ in the email address to determine if it is an exchange user
addresstype = InStr(senderaddress, "@")

' If the address is an Exchange DN use the Senders Name
If addresstype = 0 Then
senderaddress = objItem.SenderName
End If


   Const sOVIDURL As String = "http://helpdesk.com/admin"
   Const lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4

      Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      ie.Visible = True
      ie.navigate sOVIDURL

      dtTimer = Now
      lAddTime = TimeValue("00:00:20")

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

      ie.document.getElementById("user").Value = "yourusername"
      ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "yourpassword"
      ie.document.forms(0).submit

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

      ie.navigate "http://helpdesk.com/admin/new_ticket.php"

      Do Until ie.readystate = lREADYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not ie.busy
      DoEvents
      If dtTimer + lAddTime > Now Then Exit Do
      Loop

               While ie.busy
            DoEvents
         Wend

      ie.document.getElementById("name").Value = objItem.SenderName
      ie.document.getElementById("subject").Value = objItem.Subject
      ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = objItem.Body
      dtTimer = Now
      lAddTime = TimeValue("00:00:20")
   Set ie = Nothing ' If you want to close it.


'Dim PageNumber As Object


Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveInspector.currentItem
Case Else
End Select
End Function
```